# Spring Cloud Brixton.RELEASE zuul

Tags: netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I am newer in spring cloud, in my project (a microservice project build with spring boot), I used spring cloud version Brixton.RC2, and it worked fine. but when I try to upgrade its version to Brixton.RELEASE, the project is not work with zuul (if I access web microservice directly, it works, but if I access through zuul, it does not work), I didn't change anything in configuration. the maven dependency is:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>Brixton.RC2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

can anyone specify what goes wrong with my project?

Thanks and Best regards!!

Comment: Above code works fine, but if I change (and only change) the version to Brixton.RELEASE, it does not work. Even, I tried to change the artifactId to "spring-cloud-dependencies" according to https://spring.io/blog/2016/05/11/spring-cloud-brixton-release-is-available

Comment: what is the error that you are seeing can you add that please. also add your full pom file if it is a build error.

Comment: The strange thing is no build error, no runtime error in console. when I access system through zuul port, the login page is displayed, but it will redirect to the error page whatever I input, also I cannot find any error in the web layer or zuul, while if I revert the version to RC2, it succeed

Comment: if the issue is specific to zuul what version of spring-cloud-starter-zuul is getting download on both BRIXTON version.. are they the same.... if they are the same then there is something else thats causing the issue.

Comment: Hi Grinish, Thanks you for following up my question. Per my check, the zuul version is changed, when the version of org.springframework.cloud is "Brixton.RC2" the version of spring-cloud-starter-zuul is "1.1.0.RC2", when the version of spring cloud is "Brixton.RELEASE", the version of spring-cloud-starter-zuul is "zuul-1.1.0.RELEASE"

Comment: then if the issue is specific to zuul then why not pull the RC2 version with Brixton RELEASE just to see if it works so that the issue can be narrowed down to zuul. if after using zuul RC2 version with brixton-Release all is fine then there is definately something missing in the RELEASE  that is in RC2.

Comment: @Grinish sorry for later response you, as I have no idea to test this. Now, this problem is solved by Fahad's solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I have the same problem . I was on Brixton.M4 and upgraded to Brixton.Release . What is happening is , when you login , the request is hitting gateway and is being routed to ouath server . But when zuul routes the login request , the header is missing . ie the authorization header with base64 of clientId:clientSecret is missing . This is because of Sensitive Headers in zuul , which is new in Spring Cloud Netflix 1.1 . Please refer https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-netflix.adoc#cookies-and-sensitive-headers for more information.

Add

> zuul.routes.myroute.sensitiveHeaders=''

to your application.yml or application.properties , which will overwrite the default value of sensitiveHeaders to empty .

Comment: Will try this solution, and feedback later, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried this configuration in my project, it works.